# An adjective to indicate that there is too much text on a slide

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

> Your slide is too *adj*

What's an adjective to indicate that there are [too many words](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/powerpoint-130220084826-phpapp01/95/powerpoint-16-638.jpg?cb=1361350200) on a slide?

Comment: Too *dense*, too *busy*, is an *eye-chart*, etc.

Comment: I like the fact that you included a wordy slide discouraging the use of such slides.

Comment: "There are too any words on your slide"

Comment: "*there is too many words*" vs "*there are too many words*"

Comment: I'm often tempted to use the word _novelistic_ in such cases.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected it.

Comment: "Busy" is the term I'd reach for first.

Comment: *text-heavy slides*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Wordy

If I were to type about sixteen paragraphs describing what exactly this word really means, then that would be a very *wordy* explanation.

**Crowded** is another option, if you're just referring to the unavailability of white space.

Answer (score 6):

This slide is too **cluttered**.

This slide is too **busy**.

This slide makes me feel **claustrophobic**.

I also like **dense**, which was proposed in a comment.

Comment: Very good. "Cluttered" is my own favourite in this usage.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific to slides or PowerPoints, but you could use "**verbose**".

> **verbose** *adj.*
>
> characterised by the use of many or too many words; wordy
>
> *noun: **verboseness***

*Source: Dictionary.com*